# Noun for 'love'?

Tags: translation

Is there a noun form for the word love in Japanese?

I know saying すき(suki) or だいすき(daisuki) 
can be interpreted as "I love/like you" but I am not sure if these are also nouns and if so how to use in a way that would not be misinterpreted?

Comment: Have you tried to check a (any) dictionary?

Comment: daisuki is だいすき in hiragana, which is important if you want the right kanji, 大好き。

Comment: This is basically a misguided question: the word "love" is an English word, and in Japanese you need to learn Japanese words. Of course there are cases where there is a noun in English ("isobar" for example) and there is a corresponding noun in Japanese (等圧線), and there are probably no cases where this correspondence fails. But love (in particular!) is not like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible candidates include but aren't limited to (also, I marked the する verbs and な adjectives):

> [愛]{あい}(する) love; to love
>
> [恋]{こい} romantic love
>
> [好]{す}き(な) liked; fond of; love
>
> [大好]{だいす}き(な) very liked; very fond of; loving a lot
>
> [愛好]{あいこう}(する) love; adoration; to love; to adore
>
> [恋愛]{れんあい}(する) love; love-making; passion; emotion; affection; to love; to make love; to be passionate; to be emotional; to be affectionate

I'm not a native speaker, so sorry if I messed up some of the nuances of each.

Answer (score 2):

The noun for "love" is 愛（あい）(ai).

Answer (score 2):

There are two words. [愛]{あい} is for any kind of love, romantic or not (though mostly romantic); [恋]{こい} is for romance specifically.